# JQuery GET assigning data

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry, but I am new to jQuery so this may seem like a dumb question.

I have a generic function that will call a `$.get` to retrieve some data from a URL and I then want to assign to a variable, not a control.

Here's my function, it has been simplified to clear out the "noise"...

```
function LoadFromURL(url) {
    var response = "";
    $("textarea#dump").val("url=" + url);   // Shows the URL, no problem

    $.get(url, "", function (data) {
        response = data;
        $("textarea#dump").val(response);   // Shows the data, no problem
    });

    $("textarea#dump").val(response);   // Shows NOTHING!
    return (response);
}
```

The problem is that the `response` value quite happily assigns inside the callback function, but when it gets to the `return (response)` then the variable is empty.

Comment: Following Quentin's link shows just how little I know about jQuery/Ajax...

Having read the linked question, I now understand that I need to refactor the code for asynchronous operation.

Answer (score 0):

The `Shows NOTHING` line is fired too soon to be useful.  You must start from the callback function and go from there.  You could call a method from the callback.

Call it like this:

```
var cb = function(data) {
  $("textarea#dump").val(data);  
}
LoadFromUrl("someUrl", cb);
```

or inline like this:

```
LoadFromUrl("someUrl", function(data) {
   $("textarea#dump").val(data);  
});
```

Change your method like this:

```
function LoadFromURL(url, cb) {
  $("textarea#dump").val("url=" + url);   // Shows the URL, no problem


  $.get(url, "", function (data) {
     cb(data);  //<-- call the CallBack method
  });

}
```

This is more the behavior of javascript than jQuery, callbacks are a way of life in js.